# Playwright - URL is not loading sometimes

Tags: testing, automated-tests, playwright, gui-testing, playwright-java

when I start the test, the browser is opened but it does not load the URL.
After 10-15 seconds it stopped to load (see screenshot).
I had updated intelliJ, updated playwright to version 1.28.1 (doesn't help)
It happened 7 out of 10 trials.

**Any idea why it suddenly becomes that behavior?**

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: please share the config and code which you used for the execution. sure we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 probabilities causing this error when hitting the URL:

1. Your browser version could be a outdated which the site is blocking, so try updating playwright browsers using the command 'npx playwright install'.
2. Check whether the site is being blocked due to any firewall or proxy setting and if so, get it whitelisted.
3. As the request also seems to be a crash due to timeout, kindly check whether you have decent internet speed.